# WinRT: How to add a new button in the Start Screen bottom appbar options

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-8.1

When selecting a tile in the Start Screen the bottom appbar shows up with options.
Is it possible to add a new button to this appbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the start screen is completely locked down; there is no programmatic access at all.